# Jquery .click event not firing on first click on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

As the title says, I have a click event bound to a navigation comprised of h1 tags.

For some reason, the event is not firing for these specific `h1` tags (I've confirmed this with alerts), however other click events seem to be firing fine on the site.

Its working on desktop, and on mobile if I click the target once, wait a second and then click it again the event fires.

I'm testing on an iPhone 6 running the Google Chrome browser.

Link for the curious: 
[leoportodemo.appspot.com](http://leoportodemo.appspot.com/)

Comment: I've seen on some mobiles where .click wasn't working well (not even after a delay), where it turned out that .on("click", .... was working just fine. So give it a shot.

Comment: ^ this didn't work unfortunately.   It seems like the problem was the browser was focusing on the h1 element.  Fixed it by adding a <h1 ontouchstart="mobileTouch(event)"> event and just doing the same action from there.  Kind of annoying but seems like it had to be done.

Comment: sorry couldn't be of help, hopefully touchstart is not gonna give headaches with touch vs click